# Count unique elements along an axis of a NumPy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a three-dimensional array like

```
A=np.array([[[1,1],
[1,0]],

[[1,2],
[1,0]],

[[1,0],
[0,0]]])
```

Now I would like to obtain an array that has a nonzero value in a given position if only a unique nonzero value (or zero) occurs in that position. It should have zero if only zeros or more than one nonzero value occur in that position. For the example above, I would like

```
[[1,0],
[1,0]]
```

since

- in `A[:,0,0]` there are only `1`s
- in `A[:,0,1]` there are `0`, `1` and `2`, so more than one nonzero value
- in `A[:,1,0]` there are `0` and `1`, so `1` is retained
- in `A[:,1,1]` there are only `0`s

I can find how many nonzero elements there are with `np.count_nonzero(A, axis=0)`, but I would like to keep `1`s or `2`s even if there are several of them. I looked at `np.unique` but it doesn't seem to support what I'd like to do.

Ideally, I'd like a function like `np.count_unique(A, axis=0)` which would return an array in the original shape, e.g. `[[1, 3],[2, 1]]`, so I could check whether 3 or more occur and then ignore that position.

---

All I could come up with was a list comprehension iterating over the that I'd like to obtain

```
[[len(np.unique(A[:, i, j])) for j in range(A.shape[2])] for i in range(A.shape[1])]
```

Any other ideas?

Comment: If I understand correctly, `np.count_nonzero(A, axis=0)` solves your first problem. The next part is to keep the unique 1's and 2's from the list, right? Why not just use [np.greater](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.greater.html) for this? And just append the resulting list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach would be to use `A` as first axis indices for setting a boolean array of the same lengths along the other two axes and then simply counting the non-zeros along the first axis of it. Two variants would be possible - One keeping it as `3D` and another would be to reshape into `2D` for some performance benefit as indexing into `2D` would be faster. Thus, the two implementations would be -

```
def nunique_axis0_maskcount_app1(A):
    m,n = A.shape[1:]
    mask = np.zeros((A.max()+1,m,n),dtype=bool)
    mask[A,np.arange(m)[:,None],np.arange(n)] = 1
    return mask.sum(0)

def nunique_axis0_maskcount_app2(A):
    m,n = A.shape[1:]
    A.shape = (-1,m*n)
    maxn = A.max()+1
    N = A.shape[1]
    mask = np.zeros((maxn,N),dtype=bool)
    mask[A,np.arange(N)] = 1
    A.shape = (-1,m,n)
    return mask.sum(0).reshape(m,n)
```

Runtime test -

```
In [154]: A = np.random.randint(0,100,(100,100,100))

# @B. M.'s soln
In [155]: %timeit f(A)
10 loops, best of 3: 28.3 ms per loop

# @B. M.'s soln using slicing : (B[1:] != B[:-1]).sum(0)+1
In [156]: %timeit f2(A)
10 loops, best of 3: 26.2 ms per loop

In [157]: %timeit nunique_axis0_maskcount_app1(A)
100 loops, best of 3: 12 ms per loop

In [158]: %timeit nunique_axis0_maskcount_app2(A)
100 loops, best of 3: 9.14 ms per loop
```

---

**Numba method**

Using the same strategy as used for `nunique_axis0_maskcount_app2` with directly getting the counts at C-level with `numba`, we would have -

```
from numba import njit

@njit
def nunique_loopy_func(mask, N, A, p, count):
    for j in range(N):
        mask[:] = True
        mask[A[0,j]] = False
        c = 1
        for i in range(1,p):
            if mask[A[i,j]]:
                c += 1
            mask[A[i,j]] = False
        count[j] = c
    return count

def nunique_axis0_numba(A):
    p,m,n = A.shape
    A.shape = (-1,m*n)
    maxn = A.max()+1
    N = A.shape[1]
    mask = np.empty(maxn,dtype=bool)
    count = np.empty(N,dtype=int)
    out = nunique_loopy_func(mask, N, A, p, count).reshape(m,n)
    A.shape = (-1,m,n)
    return out
```

Runtime test -

```
In [328]: np.random.seed(0)

In [329]: A = np.random.randint(0,100,(100,100,100))

In [330]: %timeit nunique_axis0_maskcount_app2(A)
100 loops, best of 3: 11.1 ms per loop

# @B.M.'s numba soln
In [331]: %timeit countunique2(A,A.max()+1)
100 loops, best of 3: 3.43 ms per loop

# Numba soln posted in this post
In [332]: %timeit nunique_axis0_numba(A)
100 loops, best of 3: 2.76 ms per loop
```

Comment: `nunique_axis0_numba`  and `countunique2` take exactly the same time on my computer.

Comment: @B.M. Yup, added yours too with the max number from `A` as `A.max()` to be fair to both the solutions. Yours a tiny bit slower :)

Answer (score 4):

You can use `np.diff` to stay at numpy level for the second task.

```
def diffcount(A):
    B=A.copy()
    B.sort(axis=0)
    C=np.diff(B,axis=0)>0
    D=C.sum(axis=0)+1
    return D

# [[1 3]
#  [2 1]]
```

it's seems to be a little faster on big arrays:

```
In [62]: A=np.random.randint(0,100,(100,100,100))

In [63]: %timeit diffcount(A)
46.8 ms ± 769 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [64]: timeit [[len(np.unique(A[:, i, j])) for j in range(A.shape[2])]\
for i in range(A.shape[1])]
149 ms ± 700 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Finally counting unique is simpler than sorting, a `ln(A.shape[0])`  factor can be win.

A way to win this factor is to use the set mechanism :

```
In [81]: %timeit np.apply_along_axis(lambda a:len(set(a)),axis=0,A) 
183 ms ± 1.17 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Unfortunately, this is not faster.

Another way is to do it by hand :

```
def countunique(A,Amax):
    res=np.empty(A.shape[1:],A.dtype)
    c=np.empty(Amax+1,A.dtype)
    for i in range(A.shape[1]):
        for j in range(A.shape[2]):
            T=A[:,i,j]
            for k in range(c.size): c[k]=0 
            for x in T:
                c[x]=1
            res[i,j]= c.sum()
    return res
```

At python level:

```
In [70]: %timeit countunique(A,100)
429 ms ± 18.7 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Which is not so bad for a pure python approach. Then just shift this code at low level with numba :

```
import numba    
countunique2=numba.jit(countunique)  

In [71]: %timeit countunique2(A,100)
3.63 ms ± 70.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Which will be difficult to improve a lot.

Comment: `(B[1:] != B[:-1]).sum(0)+1` might be faster, specially with arrays of large first axis lengths.

Comment: @Divakar : slighty better, but sort take the a lot of  time here.

Comment: Add the setup used for timings for completeness?

Comment: Added timings for slicing based alongwith two of mine using mask initialization based ones in my post.

Comment: Your function should probably return something.

Comment: Could you do a value check between the numba approach and `f`? I am getting mistmatch. Also, the timings for `numba` seems really big, maybe because you are summing `.sum()` in it forcing njit ineffective? I am on `'0.35.0'` numba.

Comment: Thanks, it's good now, I used two time the `i` index. I don't  find it so big, I have a 1 GHz processor.

Comment: Am I missing something in `countunique2`? `T` has the same length as the axis 0 of the initial array `A`, but `c` keeps track of which labels have been found along that axis for each element `[:, i, j]`? So if I have more labels (`len(c)=A.max()+1`?) than axis 0 is long, I have undefined values somewhere in `c`?