# Speed up uncertainty calculation

Tags: python

I want to calculate a uncertainty score for a monte carlo dropout for active learning purpose. 
I have T predictions of the same image and currently I am calculating a entropy for the predictions on every pixel with the following function. The function should return a higher value if the predicted classes are different (e.g. for T = 3: [ 1, 2, 3]) and low when the classes are equal (e.g. [ 1, 1, 1])

```
def calculate_entropy(labels, base=e):
    value,counts = np.unique(labels, return_counts=True)
    norm_counts = counts / counts.sum()
    return -(norm_counts * np.log(norm_counts)/np.log(base)).sum()
```

I have the prediction results in a array shape like this: `[T, Height, Width]` and a output shape of `[Height, Width]`. Because I want a entropy for every row I call the function like that: np.apply_along_axis(func1d=calculate_entropy, axis=1, arr=data)

The function takes 3 seconds for one image with multiple predictions, which is way to high. Anyone has a suggestion how to improve this?

Example input:

```
preds = np.array([
[[0, 2, 0],
 [1, 1, 0]],

[[0, 2, 9],
 [1, 2, 9]],

 [[1, 1, 0],
 [2, 2, 9]],

 [[1, 1, 9],
 [3, 2, 9]],
])
```

Example output:

```
[[0.69314718 0.69314718 0.69314718]
 [1.03972077 0.56233514 0.56233514]]
```

Comment: 5 different classes are possible. And there are 3-4k images.

Comment: So your input has the shape `(width, height, classes)` and your output the shape `(width, classes)`?

Comment: My guess is you meant an output with shape `(width, height)` but then you would be using `axis=0`

Comment: You are right, my answer was wrong, sorry about that. I still think that a similar approach is likely going to work, so here's the link again: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46894281/2111778